# changing ng2-charts label text on imported chart data

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I am importing data into graph chart (ng2-charts in angular 2) and i am loading data from a json file. I wanted to know how can i override the label text on the graph?

Here is a plunker of what i have: https://plnkr.co/edit/xr6xs6PmaF9iQ6DsRnHT?p=preview

on the top of the graph there is `Label 0` i would like to override/change that label text to say: `Test Results` How can i go about doing that with my current code structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fist, please update your question to include your code from plunker. Just in case that plunker gets deleted.

you'll have to use `datasets` input instead of `data` to take advantage of legend labels.

> plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/UUW0uHdyVacK7ZMqUsp0?p=preview

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {ChartsModule, Color} from 'ng2-charts';
import { Http, Response, HttpModule, JsonpModule  } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { DataService } from './service';
import { IDataChart } from './dataChart';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [DataService],
  template: `
    <div style="width:100%; display:block">
      <canvas *ngIf="loaded" baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
      </canvas>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  barChartOptions: any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]
    }
  };
  barChartLabels: string[] =[];
  barChartType: string = 'horizontalBar';
  barChartLegend: boolean = true;
  barChartData: any[] =[];
  resultData: IDataChart[] =[];
  loaded = false;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
  }

  getData(){
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data => {
      this.resultData = data;
      this.barChartLabels = this.resultData.map(item => item.label);
      var d=this.resultData.map(item => item.data)
      this.barChartData = this.resultData.map(item => <any>{"data":Array.of(item.data), "label":item.label}); // <-- map to correct data structure for 'datasets'
      console.log(this.barChartData)
      // add new data set
      //this.barChartData.push({data:[200], label:"new data set"})
      this.loaded = true;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule,
    ChartsModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule
  ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Since i didn't need a specific label for each item i altered it for my needs as so: `"label":"Test Results"` - Thank you much for your help.

Comment: Thanks for this -- your plunker was just what I needed